# Ruby remove parts of a string

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have a problem with some regular expressions in Ruby. This is the situation:
Input text:

```
"NU POSTA aşa ceva pe Facebook! „Prostia se plăteşte”
Publicat la: 10.02.2015 10:20 Ultima actualizare: 10.02.2015 10:35
Adresa de e-mail la care vrei sa primesti STIREA atunci cand se intampla
Abonează-te
---- Here is some usefull text --- 
Abonează-te
× Citeşte mai mult »
Adauga un comentariu"
```

I need a regular expression witch can extract only useful text between "Abonează-te" word.

I tried this `result = result.gsub(/^[.]{*}\nAbonează-te/, '')` to remove the text from the start of the string to the 'Abonează-te' word, but this does not work. I have no ideea how to solve this situation. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using regular expression, you can use [`String#split`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-split), then take the second part:

```
s = "NU POSTA aşa ceva pe Facebook! „Prostia se plăteşte”
Publicat la: 10.02.2015 10:20 Ultima actualizare: 10.02.2015 10:35
Adresa de e-mail la care vrei sa primesti STIREA atunci cand se intampla
Abonează-te
---- Here is some usefull text --- 
Abonează-te
× Citeşte mai mult »
Adauga un comentariu"
s.split('Abonează-te', 3)[1].strip  # 3: at most 3 parts
# => "---- Here is some usefull text ---"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to get multiple matches:

```
s = "NU
Abonează-te
-- Here's some
Abonează-te
text --
Abonează-te
comentariu"
s.split('Abonează-te')[1..-2].map(&:strip)
# => ["-- Here's some", "text --"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is an interesting alternative.

Comment: @kitz This is not an alternative. This is the right way to go. Other answers using `scan` or `gsub` are strategically wrong for this purpose.

Comment: What if `s = "NU Abonează-te\n-- Here's some Abonează-te text --\nAbonează-te comentariu"`?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `string.scan` function. You don't need to go for `string.gsub` function where you want to extract a particular text.

```
> s = "NU POSTA aşa ceva pe Facebook! „Prostia se plăteşte”
" Publicat la: 10.02.2015 10:20 Ultima actualizare: 10.02.2015 10:35
" Adresa de e-mail la care vrei sa primesti STIREA atunci cand se intampla
" Abonează-te
" ---- Here is some usefull text --- 
" Abonează-te
" × Citeşte mai mult »
" Adauga un comentariu"
=> "NU POSTA aşa ceva pe Facebook! „Prostia se plăteşte”\nPublicat la: 10.02.2015 10:20 Ultima actualizare: 10.02.2015 10:35\nAdresa de e-mail la care vrei sa primesti STIREA atunci cand se intampla\nAbonează-te\n---- Here is some usefull text --- \nAbonează-te\n× Citeşte mai mult »\nAdauga un comentariu"
irb(main):010:0> s.scan(/(?<=Abonează-te\n)[\s\S]*?(?=\nAbonează-te)/)
=> ["---- Here is some usefull text --- "]
```

Remove the newline `\n` character present inside the lookarounds if necessary. `[\s\S]*?` will do a non-greedy match of space or non-space characters zero or more times.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/jN7uC0/1)

Comment: Good, but could you not strengthen it by adding a capture group and replacing the lookarounds with non-capture groups that included anchors? (Readers: Ruby's lookarounds cannot contain variable-length matches, which are needed to use anchors if the entire text before and after the juicy bits is not to be included.)  A small request: could you please remove the IRB prompts? They offend my sensibilities.

Comment: you mean this `s.scan(/Abonează-te.*\n([\s\S]*?)\nAbonează-te/)[0]` . Ahh, i forget that. @CarySwoveland please check my edit  is right or wrong.

Comment: For `s = "NU Abonează-te\n-- Here's some useful Abonează-te text --\nAbonează-te comentariu"`, `s[/(?:^.*?Abonează-te\n)(.*?)(?:\nAbonează-te.*$)/,1] #=> "-- Here's some useful Abonează-te text --"`.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex syntax is incorrect `.` inside of a character class means match a dot literally, and the `{*}` matches an opening curly brace "zero or more" times followed by a closing curly brace.

You can match instead of replacing here.

```
s.match(/Abonează-te(.*?)Abonează-te/m)[1].strip()
```